# many same code for button (Short Then)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have this code on the Android Eclipse and I need to short the codes to decrease file size I think can short codes with for method but I'm amateur:

```
        Button P1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part1);
    Button P2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part2);
    Button P3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part3);
    Button P4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part4);
    Button P5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part5);
    Button P6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part6);
    Button P7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part7);
    Button P8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part8);
    Button P9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part9);
    Button P10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part10);
    Button P11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part11);
    Button P12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part12);
    Button P13 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part13);
    Button P14 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part14);
    Button P15 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part15);
    Button P16 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part16);
    Button P17 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part17);
    Button P18 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part18);
    Button P19 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part19);
    Button P20 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part20);
    Button P21 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part21);
    Button P22 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part22);
    Button P23 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part23);
    Button P24 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part24);
    Button P25 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part25);
    Button P26 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part26);
    Button P27 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part27);
    Button P28 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part28);
    Button P29 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part29);
    Button P30 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part30);
    Button P31 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part31);
    Button P32 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part32);
    Button P33 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part33);
    Button P34 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part34);
    Button P35 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part35);
    Button P36 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part36);
    Button P37 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part37);
    Button P38 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part38);
    Button P39 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part39);
    Button P40 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part40);
    Button P41 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part41);
    Button P42 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part42);
    Button P43 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part43);
    Button P44 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part44);
    Button P45 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part45);
    Button P46 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part46);
    Button P47 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part47);
    Button P48 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part48);
    Button P49 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part49);
    Button P50 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part50);
    Button P51 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part51);
    Button P52 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part52);
    Button P53 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part53);
    Button P54 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part54);
    Button P55 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part55);
    Button P56 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part56);
    Button P57 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part57);
    Button P58 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part58);
    Button P59 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part59);
    Button P60 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part60);
    Button P61 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part61);
    Button P62 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part62);
    Button P63 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part63);
    Button P64 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part64);
    Button P65 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part65);
    Button P66 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part66);
    Button P67 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part67);
    Button P68 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part68);
    Button P69 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part69);
    Button P70 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part70);
    Button P71 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part71);
    Button P72 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part72);
    Button P73 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part73);
    Button P74 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part74);
    Button P75 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part75);
    Button P76 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part76);
    Button P77 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part77);
    Button P78 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part78);
    Button P79 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part79);
    Button P80 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part80);
    Button P81 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part81);
    Button P82 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part82);
    Button P83 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part83);
    Button P84 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part84);
    Button P85 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part85);
    Button P86 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part86);
    Button P87 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part87);
    Button P88 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part88);
    Button P89 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Part89);
```

Thanks very long I need a code to short the codes on top.

Comment: If all the buttons share common type of functionality and UI, you should use RecyclerView or some ListView type with a proper adapter. Adapter are meant  for such  task.

Comment: Creating a for loop for this code will hardly decrease the file size by anything at all.

Comment: simple solution was make a forloop of buttons u can esayly find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the parent layout contain only those button view you can do

```
for(int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                        Button button = (Button)layout.getChildAt(i);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the buttons shares common type of functionality and UI, you should use `RecyclerView` or some `ListView` type with a proper adapter. Adapter are meant for such task. Please upload ScreenShots of your app, to get better understanding of problem. But one thing for sure that finding 90 Buttons ID is not a good way.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using ListView or RecyclerView for list layout.

Or let's use databinding. With databinding, you can avoid `findById` method.
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html

In you build.gradle :

```
android {
    ....
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

In your layout file, use  tag like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   ... your original layout tags ...

</layout>
```

In you java program, use DataBindingUtil like this:

```
MainActivityBinding binding;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.main_activity);

   //you can access buttons like this:
   binding.Part1.setOnClickListener(...);
}
```